# loop statement with nulls?

Tags: php, sql, database

What I'm trying to do is go through the columns where task1, task2, etc prints the task and adds a yes/no radio button, but if it's null not prints the radio button. Is this a switch case? How do I accomplish in the shortest code the complete is over 200 lines as it is.

Currently, even if the tasks are empty it puts the option(radio button) for all lines

Here is the code.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM PMList where AssetNum= '$AssetNum';";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($result->num_rows > 0)

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task1'];
            echo "</td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task1C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task1C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task2'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task2C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task2C' value='No'>No"; 
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task3'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task3C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task3C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task4'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task4C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task4C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task5'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task5C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task5C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task6'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task6C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task6C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task7'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task7C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task7C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task8'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task8C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task8C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task9'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task9C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task9C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task10'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task10C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task10C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task11'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task11C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task11C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task12'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task12C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task12C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task13'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task13C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task13C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='ffffff' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task14'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='ffffff'><input type='radio' name='Task14C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task14C' value='No'>No";
            echo "<tr border='0'><td bgcolor='#D8D8D8' align='Left'>";
            echo "<font size='2'>";
            echo $row['Task15'];
            echo "</font></td><td bgcolor='D8D8D8'><input type='radio' name='Task15C' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='Task15C' value='No'>No";
            echo "</td></table><Br><table border='0' width='80%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='45' bgcolor='#ffffff' align='center'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td border='0' width='50%'>";
            echo "&nbsp; Comments:";
            echo "<br> <br> <textarea align='center' cols='60' rows='4' name='Comments'></textarea>";
            echo "</td><td border='0' width='50%'>";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Repairs Made: ";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='Repairs' value='Yes'>Yes";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='Repairs' value='No'>No";
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; If NO explain:";
            echo "<br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  <textarea align='right' cols='60' rows='4' name='Explained'></textarea>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<P><P>";
            echo "<table border='0' width='80%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='45' bgcolor='#ffffff' align='center'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td border='0'>";
            echo "&nbsp; Parts Needed:";
            echo "<br> <br> <textarea align='center' cols='132' rows='3' name='Parts'></textarea>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<P><P>";
            echo "<center><input type='submit' name='txtbutton' value='SUBMIT' />";
            echo "</form>";

        }
        else
        {
        echo "0 results";
        }

        $con->close();
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the task is null or not inside your loop doing something like so:

```
if(!is_null($row['task1']) && $row['task1'] != "")
{
  // here echo your radio button 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused if its not null then echo the radio button and i would need to do a task2 if statement? thru all tasks correct.?

Comment: you just want to check for task1 and task two ??

Comment: no I have up to 15 tasks. so it could end at task 7 lets say. as it is right now it will add the radio button to tasks 8- 15 even if null

Comment: yep you can check for all of them !

Comment: 15 if else statements and if not null do a {}? this is shortest code?

Comment: 15 if else statements and if null do a {}?else {my code} this is shortest code? can I do 2 loops or something.?

Answer (score 0):

To check all of the tasks in a very short code:

```
foreach(range(1,15) as $taskNumber){
  if(is_null($row["task{$taskNumber}"]) OR empty($row["task{$taskNumber}"]))
     echo "The task number: $taskNumber is null or empty<br>";
}
```

Put this code inside your while loop, and now you know if one of the tasks is empty or null.